# 2 unknown processes whose user is root taking 100% cpu , command = [sync_supers]

Tags: 14.04, command-line, cpu, process

I ran the `top` command and I see two processes created by root.

This is what the list of processes looks like:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
40467 root      20   0   27244    948    764 R 100.0  0.0  25613:12 [sync_supers]
58420 root      20   0   27128   2056   1616 R 100.0  0.0  18348:42 [sync_supers]
```

I search about this a lot and saw that these processes are always there but does not take up this much CPU.

- Are these processes harmful?
- Should I kill these processes ?

  - Or rebooting system would work?

Comment: it's strange it's been running for that long... there's a response to similar question here: [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/643892/high-cpu-load-on-centos-with-process-sync-supers). As per the linked answer, I'd try strace first, to see what calls are being made by the process, then kill -STOP and investigate /proc. Finally reboot and see if it appears again.

Comment: Tracing the process got me nothing.
Though processes are gone after rebooting system.
Thanks :)